# How to create a Cosmos DB Sql Container with analytical storage enabled using PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi, azure-cloud-shell

I am writing a PowerShell script where I need to create multiple Cosmos DB Containers using the SQL api.

I already enable analytical storage when creating the Cosmos DB Account :

```
New-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -Location $locations -Name $cosmosAccountName `
    -ApiKind $apiKind -EnableAutomaticFailover:$true `
    -DefaultConsistencyLevel $consistencyLevel `
    -MaxStalenessIntervalInSeconds $maxStalenessInterval `
    -MaxStalenessPrefix $maxStalenessPrefix `
    -EnableAnalyticalStorage $true
```

I then create a Cosmos DB SQL Database and follow by creating the containers.
I would like to enable analytical storage using -AnalyticalStorageTtl -1 like this:

```
New-AzCosmosDBSqlContainer `
    -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName `
    -AccountName $cosmosAccountName `
    -DatabaseName $databaseName `
    -Name $cosmosDbContainerName1 `
    -PartitionKeyKind Hash `
    -PartitionKeyPath $partitionKeyPath `
    -AnalyticalStorageTtl -1
```

But I get an error saying "-AnalyticalStorageTtl -1 is not recognized as a cmdlet[...]".
This parameter is not available on the PowerShell cmdlet. However it is available using [this Azure CLI command.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/cosmosdb/sql/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_cosmosdb_sql_container_create)

Am I missing something or is this parameter not available with the PS cmdlet? Are there any workarounds with PowerShell?

Comment: This appears to be missing as you've noted. Checking on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. I checked and this indeed was missed in the Cosmos DB PowerShell cmdlets. A [Pull Request](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/pull/13895) has been submitted to correct this and it should appear in the next [customer release](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/milestones) on Jan 19. --Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt attention to this matter. In the meantime, I use the Azure CLI command in the .ps1 script as a workaround :  az cosmosdb sql container create